# Vue.js issue with routes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I have single page application on Vuejs and main page is on localhost/. I want make admin panel. I created new component Bots and route for it 'localhost/panel/bots'. When I open this page I recived an error

```
http://localhost/panel/index.js
```

because I have link on app

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
```

in my main template.

How to resolve this issue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/index.js"></script>
```

this will make your browser load `index.js` from root `/` catalog, not `/panel`